# Adding option from input dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add `<input name="input">` values to `<select>` `<options>` each time when I change the value with `onblur` function.

In this case it does change the value of `<input name="output">` but I would like to add them multiple, so that's why I'm looking for adding values in to `select` `options`.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

```js
function add(form) {
  form.output.value = form.input.value;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="input" type="text" value="" onblur="add(this.form);">
  <input tabindex="-1" name="output" type="text" value="">
  <select multiple>
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean that after changing input value , add it's value as option to select , yea it's possible
I've wrote the code see the demo at below link

https://jsfiddle.net/oxxqw71s/

and code :

```
$("select").append($('<option>', {value:v, text:v}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes this is what I was looking for. Is there any chance to make it reverse, I mean if I want to take the value out from select if I add mistakenly just in case.

Comment: Yes can get when select value changes just add this attr
onchange="selectchanged(this.value)"  to select 
then in javascript declare function with name selectchanged
like below 
function selectchanged(v)
{
//v is the value of select
}

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like below.

```js
function add(val){
  var data = val.input.value;
  val.output.value = data;
  
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = data;
  val.opt.add(option, val.opt[0]);
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="input" type="text" value="" onblur="add(this.form);">
  <input tabindex="-1" name="output" type="text" value="">
  <select multiple name="opt">
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input name="input" type="text" value="" onblur="add(this.form);">
  <input tabindex="-1" name="output" type="text" value="">
  <select multiple name="opt">
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function add(val){
  var data = val.input.value;
  val.output.value = data;

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = data;
  val.opt.add(option, val.opt[0]);

}
```